# Game becomes unresponsive after being added to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I'm learning how to make a Pacman game, so I made a JPanel and added a keyListener on it. But I also wanted to display the high score and the current score, so I added a JFrame and put the JPanel there. Now the game will not run, although the images do load. I've tried searching on my own, but it's hard because I don't know how to describe the problem exactly.

Here is the code:

EDIT: Okay, so I have no idea why but when I put the stuff setting up the GUI at the end instead the game works again. Maybe it's the focus thing you guys were talking about? Anyways, thanks so much for your help!

```
/**
* This class creates a PacMan GUI that extends the JFrame class. It has a Board (JPanel) and 
* includes a constructor method that sets up the frame and adds a key listener to the board.
*/
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
@SuppressWarnings("serial") //takes away yellow lines

public class PacManGUI extends JFrame { 

    // Board panel
    private Board board = new Board();
    JLabel currentScoreLabel = new JLabel("Score: " + Board.score);
    JLabel highScoreLabel = new JLabel("High Score: " + Board.highScore + " by " + Board.initials);

    /**
    * PacMan GUI constructor
    * @param selectedTheme 
    */
    public PacManGUI(String selectedTheme) {

        //1. Setup the GUI
        setSize(620, 675);
        setTitle("PacMan");
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //removes the java icons that pop up when running

        add(currentScoreLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        currentScoreLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        add(highScoreLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        highScoreLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        //2. Listen for events on the board and add the board to the GUI
        add(board);
        addKeyListener(board);
        board.setFocusable(true);

        //3. Make GUI visible
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the rest of your program??

Comment: I wasn't sure if I was supposed to post my entire program, as it does have a few classes in it. I only got this problem when I attached board to the JFrame, so I only posted this class.

Comment: *"I wasn't sure if I was supposed to post my entire program,"* No, but not uncompilable code snippets either. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). *"so I added a JFrame and put the JPanel there. Now the game will not run"* Where did you see it running before?

Comment: For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing works by using layout managers. The default layout manager for a JFrame is a [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html). Read the tutorial to understand how the `BorderLayout` works.

Let the layout manager do its job and get rid of all the setBounds(...) logic.

```
wall.add(board);
//board.setVisible(true);
addKeyListener(board);
board.setFocusable(true);
//currentScore.setBounds(0,0,100,50);
wall.add(currentScore);
```

So in the code above you are trying to add two components to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` of the wall. (Note if you don't specify the constraint it defaults to CENTER). This won't work as only one component can be displayed in the CENTER so only the last on added is visible.

Instead you can try:

```
wall.add(currentScore, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

Also, the basics of your class is wrong. PacManGUI "is a" JFrame, so there is no need to create a second frame in the constructor. Look at the tutorial table of contents. There is also a section on `How to Make Frames` to get you started.

Comment: However, board still does not respond when I tap on my arrow keys. Is there something wrong with the keyListener? I've updated my code above.

Comment: KeyEvents are only dispatched to the component with focus. You should be adding the KeyListener to the Board class in its constructor. Also, you should be making the Board class focusable in the constructor. However using a KeyListener is NOT a good approach. If the Board class ever loses focus then the listener will stop working. As was mentioned above in the comments to your question you should be using `Key Bindings`.

Comment: java has so many opportunities - to keep propounding on a certain monolithic over and over again is of course your choice

Comment: @gpasch, `to keep propounding on a certain monolithic over and over again` - what does that mean?

Comment: @camickr please to revert if I'm wrong, my edit to correct small mistake